# Properly removing public/private keys

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I've been learning public/private keys and authorized_keys and made a lot of tests. I'd like to now remove them so I can start over in a clean manner.

Is removing a key as simple as this:

1. Delete the private and public key from the .ssh dir (or wherever I had the keys)
2. Remove the public key from the authorized_key file on any servers I had this on.

Are there any other steps I need to take? Any commands to clean things up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is usually as simple as the two steps you mentioned.

If you added your key to `~/.ssh/config` for automatically picking the right key to use with the right host with an `IdentityFile` directive, you may also want to remove them from there.

You may also want to remove, on your ssh client machine(s), the line(s) in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` that refer to the ssh server(s) you connected to, so that the client also forgets about the server.

Comment: It's mostly a matter of removing the edits you may have done before. Basically, if you forgot, just opening with your favorite text editor the `~/.ssh/config` file should be enough for you to see what configuration blocks you added there; and then you could just remove the blocks you don't need any longer. If you don't know what I'm talking about, you likely don't have anything to remove from there :)